# Enqueue stylesheet depending on template

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I'm trying to enque stylesheet depending on template but unfortunetelly my code isn't working. What I am doing wrong?

```
 if ( is_page_template('single-location.php')) {
       function themename_include_page_specific_css() {
  wp_enqueue_style('paralax_style', get_template_directory_uri().'/paralax.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'paralax_style');
    }
```

I tried also with that one, but still nothing.

```
 function load_theme_files() {
    if (is_page_template('single-location.php')) {
      wp_enqueue_style('paralax_style', esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ).'/paralax.css');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_theme_files');
```

Comment: First, you should run `global $post; get_page_template_slug($post->ID)` on the page where you want the javascript  and see what the result is. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_template_slug/

Comment: You may actually need to add that code to your header or footer, since if you add it in the template, there is always the possibility that a different template is being loaded.

Comment: Do you have post type with slug `location`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to first register the style and then en-queue it! This might work!

```
function custom_style_method() {
    wp_register_style( 'paralax_style', get_template_directory_uri().'/paralax.css' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_style_method');

add_filter( 'template_include', 'themename_include_page_specific_css', 1000 );

function themename_include_page_specific_css( $template ){

    if ( is_page_template('single-location.php' ) ) {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'paralax_style' );
    }

return $template;
}
```

Comment: There is no requirement to register first and then en-queue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this putting this code in your function where you enqueue your other scripts and styles and it should work.

```
wp_register_style( 'template-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/templates/css/template.css', array(), '', true );

if ( is_page_template( 'template-name.php' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'template-style' );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`single-location.php` naming for a page template is very poor choice as it conflicts with default page [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png)  [`single-$posttype.php`](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post).

So I would encourage you to change the name to something like `tem-location.php`, then the following code will work, also please take a note at enqueue handler because that should also not conflict with others(I mean if you already have a script/style enqueued with handle `paralar-style` then even if you enqueue the script/style with the same handle won't work.

Also please make sure that your template location is correct, for example if you place `tem-location.php` in `page-templates` folder then you should check for `page-templates\tem-location.php`.

```
function wpse245126_load_theme_files() {
    if (is_page_template('tem-location.php')) {
      wp_enqueue_style('tem-location-style', esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ).'/paralax.css');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse245126_load_theme_files');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this filter, to filter out styles with any condition, or alternate output href string on certain templates, example:

```
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', function($href){
if(strpos($href, "name-of-allowed.css") !== false) {
return $href;
}
return false;
});
```